# Is it possible to have multiple INSERT statements using ajax call and webmethod?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

I am currently using JSON object and ajax call with webmethod to insert multiple rows of records into the database.

In other words, we can dynamically add more rows to a table and insert those rows to the database successfully with using ajax call and webmethod after the data has been stringified as JSON object.

This is working great for us.

The issue we are currently faced with is that we would like to have multiple INSERT statements within this webmethod but it is not working.

For instance, here is my JS with **data-contact-person** class:

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#empAdd", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person0">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeename' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your name..." class="form-control employeename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeetitle' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your title..." class="form-control employeetitle01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeeemail' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Your email address..." class="form-control employeeemail01" /></td>' +
                    '<td style="width:200px;"><button type="button" id="empAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="empDeletem" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#emptable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on("click", "#btnAdd", function () { //
                var rowCount = $('.data-contact-person').length + 1;
                var contactdiv = '<tr class="data-contact-person">' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourcename' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Name of income source..." class="form-control sourcename01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceaddress' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Address of income source..." class="form-control sourceaddress01" /></td>' +
                    '<td><input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceincome' + rowCount + '" placeholder="Income..." class="form-control sourceincome01" /></td>' +
                    '<td style="width:200px;"><button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>' +
                    '<button type="button" id="btnDelete1" class="deleteContact btn btn btn-danger btn-xs">Remove</button></td>' +
                    '</tr>';
                $('#maintable').append(contactdiv); // Adding these controls to Main table class
            });


            $(document).on("click", ".deleteContact", function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove(); // closest used to remove the respective 'tr' in which I have my controls 
            });

            function getAllEmpData() {
                var data = [];
                $('tr.data-contact-person').each(function () {
                    var ename = $(this).find('.employeename01').val();
                    var etitle = $(this).find('.employeetutle01').val();
                    var email = $(this).find('.employeeemail01').val();
                    var sname = $(this).find('.sourcename01').val();
                    var saddress = $(this).find('.sourceaddress01').val();
                    var sincome = $(this).find('.sourceincome01').val();
                    var alldata = {
                        'empname': ename,
                        'emptitle': etitle,
                        'mySIncome': email,
                        'empmail': sname,
                        'mySAddress': saddress,
                        'mySIncome': sincome
                    }
                    data.push(alldata);
                });
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }

            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
                console.log(data);
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'disclosures.aspx/SaveData',
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
                    success: function () {
                        alert("Data Added Successfully");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-top: 30px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body> 
   <div class="bs-example"> 
    <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div class="container">  
            <h2>closure Forms</h2>  

            <table id="emptable">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Employee Name</th>  
                        <th>Title</th>  
                        <th>Email</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  
                    <tr class="data-contact-person">  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeename" class="form-control employeename01" placeholder="Your name..." /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeetitle" class="form-control employeetitle01" placeholder="Your title..." /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="employeeemail" class="form-control employeeemail01" placeholder="Your email address..." /></td>  
                        <td>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table><br /><br />
              <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;color:steelblue;">Name and address of income source greater than $100,000.00</span> 
            <table id="maintable">  
                <thead>  
                    <tr>  
                        <th>Name</th>  
                        <th>Address</th>  
                        <th>Income</th>  
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody>  
                    <tr class="data-contact-person">  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourcename" class="form-control sourcename01" placeholder="Name of income source..." /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceaddress" class="form-control sourceaddress01" placeholder="Address of income source..." /></td>  
                        <td>  
                            <input type="text" style="width:200px;" name="sourceincome" class="form-control sourceincome01" placeholder="Income..." /></td>  
                        <td style="width:200px;">  
                            <button type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary classAdd">Add More</button>  
                        </td>  
                    </tr>  
                </tbody>  
            </table><br /><br /> 
            <button type="button" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md pull-center btn-sm">Submit</button> 
        </div>  
'//Then the SaveData webmethod:

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Shared Function SaveData(empdata As String) As String
        Dim serializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Employee))(empdata)
        Dim s As String
        Dim sql As String
        Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If
            For Each data As Employee In serializedData
                s = "INSERT INTO Employees(EmployeeNamee,email,empTitl) Values (@ename, @title,@email)"
                sql = "Select Max(employeeID) From Employees"
                'Response.Write(s)
                'Response.End()
                ' Dim con As New SqlConnection(Constr)
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(s, con)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ename", data.empName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", data.empMail)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", data.empTitle)
                ' con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                cmd.CommandText = sql
                Dim ID = cmd.ExecuteScalar() '//get retrieve last inserted key to be inserted into sourceDetails table
            Next
            For Each data As Employee In serializedData
                Using cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO SourceDetails(sourcename, sourceaddress, sourceincome,employeeID) VALUES(@sname, @saddress,@sincome, @ID)")
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sname", data.mySource)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@saddress", data.mySAddress)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sincome", data.mySIncome)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", " & ID & ")
                    '  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            Next
            con.Close()
        End Using
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class

    Public Class Employee
        Public Property mySource() As String
            Get
                Return m_mySource
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_mySource = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_mySource As String
        Public Property mySAddress() As String
            Get
                Return m_mySAddress
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_mySAddress = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_mySAddress As String
        Public Property mySIncome() As String
            Get
                Return m_mySIncome
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_mySIncome = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_mySIncome As String
        Public Property empName() As String
            Get
                Return m_empName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_empName = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_empName As String
        Public Property empMail() As String
            Get
                Return m_empMail
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_empMail = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_empMail As String
        Public Property empTitle() As String
            Get
                Return m_empTitle
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                m_empTitle = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Private m_empTitle As String
```

When I attempted to add another class called **data-contact-person2** which requires that another INSERT statement be added to the webmethod, the code blows up with error that says, @parameter @sname is required but not supplied.

So, is there anyway to manipulate the webmethod to allow for multiple INSERT statements or do I have to have multiple seperate webmethods to make my code work?

Sorry for the long code.

Comment: You've posted snippets of *working* code, though I'd suggest doing the opposite. Rather than saying "[snippet] works, but it doesn't work when I do such-and-such", I'd suggest "Such-and-such works, but [snippet] does not." - It's much easier for us to debug if we can see your non-working code. The error you're getting is simply saying that you're not passing a value to the `@sname` parameter, either because you didn't specify it in your parameter list, or the value of `data.mySource` is `null`.

Comment: @Santi, thanks,I have replaced current code with the non working code.